# Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string

Tags: xetex, hyperref, listings, pdf, luatex

My document contains section titles that are formatted by the `listings` package. (The section names are names of `configure` script switches.)

```
\subsection{\lstinline!--enable-so-version!}\label{enable-so-version}
```

I am getting the following warning when processing the LaTeX source:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\lstinline' on input line 231.
```

Can I avoid it anyhow? I would be willing to duplicate the title string without the listings formatting decoration if there were a directive to set the PDF TOC entry string manually (instead of automatically).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Many commands that works via unexpandable stuff (assignments, catcode changes, ...) do not work in bookmarks. A PDF viewer is not TeX and does not understand the TeX language.

Package `hyperref` provides `\texorpdfstring` to provide different code for the normal case and the bookmark case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{%
    \texorpdfstring{\lstinline!--enable-so-version!}%
                   {-{}-enable-so-version}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The curly braces inside `-{}-enable` prevent that the bookmark code makes a ligature and converts the two single hyphens to an en dash.
- Package `bookmark` is recommended, the bookmarks are faster up to date
  and the package provides more features.